# Azure APIM policies: allow multiple header names for sending JWT, or 'OR' condition in policies

Tags: jwt, azure-api-management

I need to configure APIM to support JWT provided in any of predefined headers. To do that I need to combine two policies by 'OR' condition but I can't find a documentation on corresponding syntax.

I have two types of client applications. Some of them send JWT in 'Authorization' token as recommended in Azure documentation:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOi....
```

while other apps use custom header name:

```
custom_token: eyJhbGciOi....
```

I need to support both. However I can't specify policies one-by-one as 'AND' condition is used in case like below:

```
<validate-jwt header name="Authorization" ... </validate-jwt>
<validate-jwt header name="custom_token" ... </validate-jwt>
```

How do I implement 'OR' condition between policies?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution. That was easier than I was afraid of:

```
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(!context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "").Equals(""))">
            <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" ..... </validate-jwt>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <validate-jwt header-name="custom_token" ..... </validate-jwt>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
```

Comment: Could be done a bit easier as: <validate-jwt header-name="@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") ? "Authorization" : "custom_token")" ..... </validate-jwt>

Comment: Is the solution the same when I simply want to use a logical OR for two `<validate-jwt>` policies that have different config endpoints? (as in to [work around this limitation](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/31936303-support-expressions-in-openid-config-url-of-valida)) If so, then what goes in the `condition="..."` ?